# Why double width = 50/110000; the output is 0.000000000000000?

Tags: java

This is my code :

```
double width = 50/110000;
System.out.println("width ori is "+width );
```

And the output is: `0.00000000000`

What's wrong ? the expected output has to be `4.5454545454545455E-4`

Any body can explain to me why?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because you're dividing two integers, so it will only take the integer part (integer division).

> Dividing integers in a computer program requires special care. Some
>   programming languages, treat integer division (i.e by giving the integer quotient as the answer). So the answer is an integer.

Examples :

```
In real life                  In Java

4/3  = 1.33333                4/3  = 1
25/12 = 2.083333              25/12 = 2
9/2 = 4.5                     9/2 = 4
50/110000 = 0.000454545       50/110000 = 0
```

You can cast one of the number (or both but it's actually useless) to `double` to avoid that :

```
double width = (double)50/110000;
double width = 50d/110000;
double width = 50.0/110000;
```

Comment: Yep check integer vs other type literals

Comment: 2 mins? 14 upvotes? according to my calculations, next minute you'll have 22 upvotes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for pointing out that I added some example to be more clear.

Comment: @ZouZou: The examples are still slightly misleading, though, because they give the impression there's an intermediate, floating-point result. There isn't. Integer division in Java (and most other languages) works in a way that never involves floating point.

Answer (score 2):

Result of `int/int` returns you an `integer`.

**So the decimal part got truncated resulting you with an integer**

You need to cast:

```
double width = (double)50/110000;
```

As @Josh M has pointed, You can also try :

```
double width = 50d / 110000d;
```

Comment: Or you could do `double width = 50d / 110000d;`

Comment: @JoshM I prefer `50.0 / 110000.0`

Comment: @JanDvorak A matter of preference, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation to what's happening:

In Java, the default type of numbers is `int`, so when you write `50/110000`, they're both considered `int`, although you defined the result to be `double`. 
When `int` division occurs, the result will be `0`, because they are both `int`s, then the `double` will hold this value, which will be represented as `double`, so you're getting `0.000000`.

Possible solutions:

- Coding these numbers with `d`: `50d/110000d`.
- Casting one side explicitly (the other will be implicitly cast): `(double)50/110000`.
- `50.0/110000`.

See [Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), it'll really help you.