# While mod 1 is not 0 Android

Tags: java, android, math

I am trying to make this loop keep repeating until a result can be modded by 1 and have a result of 0.
This is generating a divide question and I only want questions that the answer is a whole number. So the answer should be 1,2,3,4 etc but not answers with decimal places.

```
double resulta = 1.3678; // Make it run once instead of do while
while (resulta % 1 != 0) {
    int first = randInt(0,9);
    int last = randInt(0,9);
    MainActivity.result = (first / last);
    resulta = MainActivity.result;
    String Sfirst = String.valueOf(first);
    String Slast = String.valueOf(last);
    System.out.println(MainActivity.result);
    question = "" + Sfirst + " / " + Slast + " = ?";
}
```

Comment: I'm quite certain the `%` operator doesn't work on floating point data types.

Comment: @Cruncher Not on decimal values.

Comment: @ZouZou Obviously, my assumption there was x as an integer. The point I was making though, was that the code is flawed beyond the data type problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
MainActivity.result = (first / last); //you're doing an integer division here
resulta = MainActivity.result;
```

Because first and last are **both** integers, the result of this division returns an integer.

[Why does it return an integer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620225/why-double-width-50-110000-the-output-is-0-000000000000000/19620230#19620230)

But **every** integer modulo 1 returns 0 so `resulta % 1` is **always equals** to 0, hence your while loop never ends.

Comment: Division of integers isn't closed...(1/9, 2/9, etc.).

Comment: @EmbattledSwag What do you mean ?

Comment: `first` and `last` are both random integers between 0 and 9. Let's say `first` is 1 and `last` is 9. `(first/last)` would be 1/9, which is a float, not an integer.

Comment: @EmbattledSwag http://ideone.com/lZ80Is This is called integer division. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620225/why-double-width-50-110000-the-output-is-0-000000000000000/19620230#19620230

Comment: Wait, my bad. You're right. I'm an idiot. I got too caught up in number theory.

Comment: @ZouZou seeing as it's confused one already, perhaps putting that link in your question might be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You're testing `resulta % 1 != 0` and that's nonsensical because `%` is undefined for non-integers (`resulta` is a float).

Either you have to change `resulta` to be an integer or you have to expect non-integer values for your statement.

Comment: While this may explain what is wrong with his program, it doesn't answer the question and provide a method for accomplishing what is trying to be accomplished.  As such, this is probably better posted as a comment.

Comment: His (implied) question is asking why it's not working and that's what I answered. I don't think we (or maybe that's just me) understand his program enough to submit a correction to his code.

Comment: Except for questions asking `Method A` works but `Method B` doesn't work, why... the implied question ALWAYS is `How do I make it work?`

Comment: % does certainly work for non-integers in Java. For "double x = 10.3; System.out.println(x % 3);" you get 0.3000000000000007. Verified with Java 1.6.0_20-b20.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek Well that's not particularly helpful.  `10.3 % 3`?  I'd expect `1.3` (or something close) as the result...

Comment: @nhgrif, that should have been written 10.3 % 1. Sorry about the typo.

Comment: Ah okay, makes more sense now then.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while((resulta - (long)resulta) != 0) {
    //do stuff
}
```

If `resulta` is 3.14159, then `(long)resulta` will be 3.  Any time `resulta` has a decimal point, the above condition check for this `while` loop will return `true`.

Comment: Isn't this just while it's not whole?

Comment: @Cruncher I assumed that's what he'd be trying to do when he's `% 1`ing... I don't necessarily understand what he's actually trying to do with his code, he may have some logic problems, I don't know.  But this will give the results that someone who doesn't know any better might expect from `% 1`.  And because of other issues, his `while` loop will probably only ever run once if the condition is changed to this...

Comment: that's fair enough if you look at `x%5` as: `If x >= 5, x-=5, repeat`. This would give the property of `x%1==0 <=> x is whole`

Comment: @Cruncher Well, he specifies this in his question: `I only want questions that the answer is a whole number.`  I didn't really pay too much attention to other logic in his code.  But `someDouble - (long)someDouble` is the best way to check whether or not a `double` is a whole number as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part