# Java - Only Prints first name (i want full name) (another error included)

Tags: java, output

I'm making a program that reads a person's name and age, and when "zzz" is entered, it prints the names and ages of everyone who's 18 or older. Also, I want to calculate the percentage of people who's 18 or older. But, here's the problem: the code i'm posting bellow, only prints the first name (example: "Ricardo Almeida" and age "19". Output: "Ricardo : 19", but i want "Ricardo Almeida : 19). *The percentage calculation has a error too but i cant figure out whats wrong. It gives 0 all the times. (DONE!)* Thanks in advance to anyone who's reading this and trying to help.

PS: I dont want to use arrays! I already learned how to use them, but i want to know how to solve this without using them :)

```
package javaapplication38;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication38 {
private static final Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

private static String metodo1(String name, int age) {
    String frase="";
    if (age==18 | age>18) {
        frase=String.format("%s : %d %n",name,age);
    }
    return frase;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int age, counter1=0, counter2=0;
   String name, acumtxt="", aux;

   do {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        name=in.next(); in.nextLine();
        if (!"ZZZ".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            counter1++;
            do {
                System.out.print("Age: ");
                age=in.nextInt();
            } while (age<=0);
            if (age==18 | age>18) {
                counter2++;
            }
            aux=metodo1(name,age);
            acumtxt+=aux;
        }
    } while(!"ZZZ".equalsIgnoreCase(name));

    System.out.print(acumtxt);
    if (counter1>0) {
            System.out.println("The percentage of people who's 18 or older is "+ (counter2/counter1) +"%.");
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: You can replace `if (age==18 | age>18) {` with more intuitive `if (age>=18)`

Comment: _"It gives 0 all the times"_ Because you're doing integer division. This answer should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620225/why-double-width-50-110000-the-output-is-0-000000000000000/19620230#19620230

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you so much! I was trying to do if (age=>18)! Thanks again!

Comment: @user2336315 Thanks! I just needed to change counter1 and counter2 to double. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is here

```
name=in.next(); in.nextLine();
```

In this code `next()` reads and returns only one word from line until it finds whitespace or end of line. Rest of it is consumed with `readLine()`, but you ignore its result. Try maybe to with

```
name=in.nextLine();
```

to read entire line.

After that you will also have to change

```
age=in.nextInt();
```

and either use

```
age=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

or add `in.nextLine()` after it to also consume new line marks which would affect next `name` question.

```
age=in.nextInt(); in.nextLine();//add in.nextLine(); to consume new line marks
```

Comment: I was doing that. But, when it completes the first cicle, it shows "Name: Age:" when it should say "Name: " and waited for me to type the name.

Answer (score 0):

`in.next()` will read until there is a whitespace. You can use in.nextLine (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) or use `[BufferedReader]`(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead, and you can call the `readLine()` method.