# Why doesn't program calculate the interest?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class Interest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;          // number of years
        double rate;    // annual rate

        for (int r = 5; r<=10; r++ ) {
            System.out.println("\nInterest rate is  " + r + "%");
            System.out.println("**********************");
            System.out.println("Year\tAmount on deposit");

            for (n=1; n<=10; n++) {
                int p = 1000; // original amount
                rate = r / 100;
                double a = p * (Math.pow(1 + rate, n)); // amount on deposit at the end of year
                System.out.printf("\n%d\t%.2f", n, a);
             }
         }
    }

}
```

It's showing the chart correctly in terms of years. But amount on deposit at the end of year (a) stays the same (1000).It looks like this;

```
Interest rate is  5%
**********************
Year    Amount on deposit

1         1000.00
2         1000.00
3         1000.00
4         1000.00
5         1000.00
6         1000.00
7         1000.00
8         1000.00
9         1000.00
10        1000.00
```

and it goes until rate reaches 10%.

Comment: My god, do some formatting to your code!

Comment: As you sneak up on this problem, might I suggest looking at [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to avoid compounding rounding errors?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer The amount seems to be fresh calculated each time, so there is no build up of error or need for big decimal

Comment: @PaulProgrammer thanks I'm looking at it right now.

Comment: doubles are not good for financial apps.  It's OK in the realm of toy projects, but if you work with real money, you'll find as I did that people get pissed off when their 2-million $ account is off by 3 pennies (even though it's a vanishingly small percentage).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're performing [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620225/why-double-width-50-110000-the-output-is-0-000000000000000/19620230).

Try : `rate = r/100.0;`

Answer (score 1):

Comment- When you divide two integers in java, the result is another integer (rounded down). Try using a double instead in your division.

Comment: This is actually an answer, not a comment. Which is good because answers shouldn't contain comments

Comment: It is truncated, not rounded up.

Comment: woops! thanks for catching that mistake rgettman, I've fixed it.