# Calculating sample variance in Java

Tags: java

I am studying introductory Java course and I have gotten stuck with this particular exercise:

"Create the method variance, which receives a list of integers as a parameter and then returns the sample variance of that list. You can check how a sample variance is calculated in Wikipedia, under "Population variance and sample variance"."

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Variance {

    public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

         int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
           sum = sum + list.get(i);
        }

        return sum;
    }


    public static double average(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        double average = sum(list) / list.size();
        return average;
    }

    public static double variance(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

        double sumMinusAverage = sum(list) - average(list);

        double result = 1/(list.size()-1) * Math.pow(sumMinusAverage, 2);

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(3);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(2);

        System.out.println("The variance is: " + variance(list));
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why double width = 50/110000; the output is 0.000000000000000?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620225/why-double-width-50-110000-the-output-is-0-000000000000000)

Comment: `double average = sum(list) / list.size();` => integer division. Same for `1/(list.size()-1)`

Comment: Your error is in the variance function. Double check the formula.

Answer (score 1):

You have integer division resulting an a zero.  The solution is actually simpler.  BTW Math.pow is expensive

```
public static double variance(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    double sumMinusAverage = sum(list) - average(list);

    return sumMinusAverage * sumMinusAverage / (list.size()-1);
}
```