# Calculate median

Tags: java, median

I can't figure out what is wrong, why doesnt my median work ? Everything works except my median and i have been sitting here for a while and looking at it and still don't understand why it doesnt work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stat{
    private int[] värden = new int[100]; 
    public int count = 0;       // counter = 0


    public int Värden(int värde){
        värden[count++]=värde;
        return värde;
    }

    public double medelv(){                 //medelvärde
        double medelv = 0;
        int total = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < count; x++){
            total += värden[x];

            medelv = (total/count);
        }
        return medelv;
    }
    public double medianen(){
        Arrays.sort(värden);

        double medianen = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < count; x++){

        if (värden.length % 2 == 0)
            medianen = ((double)värden[värden.length/2] + (double)värden[värden.length/2 - 1])/2;
        else
            medianen = (double) värden[värden.length/2];
```

Comment: `medelv = (total/count);` You are performing integer division. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620225/why-double-width-50-110000-the-output-is-0-000000000000000/19620230. Also there is no need to compute it at each iteration.

Comment: @ZouZou he is diving double / integer isnt ?  (double + double ) / 2

Comment: @Mani I was speaking about the `medelv` method. :-) Yes, there is no integer division involved in the `medianen` method (just a useless for loop)

Comment: @ZouZou Oh.. i got it .Thanks. So Op question with medelv ahhh. My bad

Answer (score 1):

As @zouzou says in the comments, an int divided by another int equals an int. Cast one of them, and it will work.

```
medelv = ((double)total/count);
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more concise way to calculate the median:

```
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//TO DO: Add the integers to the array list
Collections.sort(integers);
double median;
if (integers.size() > 0) {
    int x = integers.size() / 2;
    else if (integers.size() % 2 == 0) 
        median = (integers.get(x - 1) + integers.get(x)) / 2.0;
    else median = integers.get(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with your logic . Other than finding it in loop . which is not required.

```
if (värden.length % 2 == 0) {
            medianen = ((double)värden[värden.length/2] + (double)värden[värden.length/2 - 1])/2;
        } else {
            medianen = värden[värden.length/2];
        }
```

If your array length is even then upper portion is double so no issues . If it is not even then you are picking middle ( 5/2 => 2.5 which would become 3 . it is median)

My question is , you declare the array length as 100. Are you filling all the 100 elements ? if not your logic will not work.