# Is this a logical error?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that decides if a player is eligible for an all-star game or not.

I am getting an ouput of "0" every time. IS this a logical error? Don't see it.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class IfElseBattingEverage 

{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      int hits;
      int atBats; 
      int batAvg; 

      // get number hits from user

      hits = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number of hits") ); 

      // get number of at bats from user 

      atBats = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number of at Bats") );  

      // calcualte batting average 

      batAvg = ((hits/atBats)*100);
      System.out.println(batAvg);



      // decision if...else
      if (batAvg >= 30 )
      {
       System.out.println ("Congratulations! You are eligible for the all-star game, with a batting average of: " + batAvg + "%");
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println ("Bummer! With a batting average of: " + batAvg + "% ,you are not eligible for the all-star game! Better luck next year!");
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: integer division....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19620230/1393766

Comment: Try (100*hits)/atBats...

Answer (score 0):

This could be your problem:

```
batAvg = ((hits/atBats)*100);
```

I would use this:

```
batAvg = (100*hits/atBats);
```

`hits/atBats` is an integer division causes mostly `0` result (if hits < atBats)